# re-update domain oject properties from jsf page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a dataTable filled with information. On selected one rown "onRowSelect" method is called. 
"Order number " outputText entry is populated with value retrieved from ProductOrder object.

```
/* Filter bean */
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
    NewOrderBean currentOrder = (NewOrderBean) FacesUtils
            .getManagedBean("newOrderBean");
    currentOrder.setOrderNum(((ProductOrder) event.getObject()).getOrderNum());
}

/* newOrderBean */
public int update() {
    ProductOrder pt = new ProductOrder ();
    try {
        pt = productService.findOrderbyNum(orderNum).get(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 0;
    }

    pt.setOrderNum(orderNum);

    try {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Product updated with: ", orderNum);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        return 1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

User, after entering new text into  "Order number ", presses Update to modify product order number.

```
<!-- JSF page -->
<ui:define id="content" name="contentBody">
    <h:form class="ViewResservation" id="viewPanel">
        <p:tabView id="tabView">
            <p:tab title="Client" id="tab1">
                    <h:outputText value="Order number " />
                <p:inputText id="ordr" value="#{newOrderBean.orderNum}" />
                </p:tab>
            </p:tabView>    
    </h:form>
</ui:define>        
    <ui:define name="footer">
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton value="Update"
                actionListener="#{newOrderBean.update}" />
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
```

Problem is that after entering new text and pressing Update, value (orderNum) stays the same. How can I get value enterted by user and 
update ProductOrder object with new order number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab must be inside the tabview element. You have it inverted.

For your problem, your order number is set in one form and your submit button in another. You need to put both in the same form else the order number isn't submitted.

Comment: yes, it works, thank you siebz0r. I have noticed that in my case each time I press "Update" and when one of the rows is selected. Page refreshes and onRowSelect method is called again. Why this happens?

Comment: I don't know why the page is refreshed. The onRowSelect is probably called because the ajax event is in the same form, but I don't know this for sure. Also if my answer answers your question, please mark it as accepted. ;-)